# how to set up and authentication system allowing admin to go the dashboard, and regular user to his profile?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to create a system login, that direct the regular users to their profiles, and direct the admin to the dashboard, using the same logging form is that possible in laravel??
i was looking for a solution for that problem, if any one have any idea how to do it??

Comment: Write a middleware and in it check the role of the user, then redirect the user to the proper route.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used Laravel's default auth scaffolding, you can [customize](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating) how the user is redirected after logging in by modifying the authenticated method in your `LoginController` :

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) { // If using spatie/laravel-permissions
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->route('profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```